# Post array into next page

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops, post

I have a hidden input with array:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->name.'" />
```

How do I post the value of this array into the next page?

I tried this method: `$a = $_POST['item_name'];` but then it gave me the following error:

> Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\BSSecureTech\payment.php on line 6
>   Array

Then I tried `$a = $_POST['item_name'][0];`. It works but then I wouldn't know how many values are in the array. How do I kind of loop the `[0]` to let it post all the values in the array?

Comment: Can you put the following script on your page and give the out put. `<pre><?php print_r($cart_items); print_r($obj); ?>`

Comment: `$_POST['item_name']['your cart item'];`

Comment: <pre><?php print_r($cart_items); print_r($obj); ?> Put this at the first page or second page?

Comment: @user3659034 ['your cart item'] refers to?

Comment: if your `$cart_items` is `test` then `$_POST['item_name']['test'];`

Comment: @user3659034 how you do define the ['test']? i dont know where exactly to locate for my cart_items. This is my code:

    $cart_items = 0;
  foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)
        {
           $product_code = $cart_itm["code"];
     $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id='$product_code' LIMIT 1");
     $obj = $results->fetch_object();
     
      echo '<li class="cart-itm">';
   echo '<h8>'.$obj->name.'</h8> ';
            echo '</li>';

   echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->name.'" />';

Comment: in your html `name="item_name['.$cart_items.']"`. I refer here `$cart_items`. if it is `test` then `$_POST['item_name']['test'];`

Comment: @user3659034 so it would be $_POST['item_name'][$cart_items]; ? It says Undefined variable.

Comment: @Revee [have posted a simple session example for you, don't forget to accept one of the answers as the right answer if they resolve your issue, see here how...](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 2):

At first i suggest you to change in your `HTML` like this if your file extension is `.php`

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name[<?=$cart_items?>]" value="<?=$obj->name?>" />
```

On `PHP` end check your `post array` like `print_r($_POST);`. Then catch your desired value by `array` index like  this

```
$values = $_POST;
$item = $_POST['item_name']['your index'];
echo $item;
```

Comment: I understand that I have to put 'index' to post it. however, I'm not sure how many input will the user enter from the first page. then how do i determine the index?